# Windows server 2008 Admin password changes after logout

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, remote-desktop

I have windows server 2008 with two administrator accounts and I have a fixed IP for it.
I access the server with remote desktop but every time I logout of any of the 2 admin accounts i can't login again until I access the other account and change the password.
This happens for both accounts.
Any ideas about how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you searched for any scripts that might run during your session?

Answer (score 0):

I might be misreading something so please correct me. Did you say that in order to login with account#1 you have to change the password for account#2 to login with acct#1? What? Or did you mean to say when you logout of acct#1 you have to change the pass for acct#1 to login again with acct#1? If the latter then have you checked for group policy password change requirements? Perhaps it's set to change every few days?